# I am trying to install dependency gevent 23.9.1 on ubuntu 20.04, failing to build wheel with python 3.10

Tags: gevent

2023-11-14T07:11:22.9039445Z #16 340.3   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-sdao04r_/wheels/b1/5a/3b/68ad7e92ddeed4f03a90dbaee823a22bb19c1553d689c90bb5
2023-11-14T07:11:22.9042412Z #16 340.3   Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): started
2023-11-14T07:12:25.1117159Z #16 402.6   Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): still running...
2023-11-14T07:13:39.6999514Z #16 477.1   Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): still running...
2023-11-14T07:13:40.9036251Z #16 478.3   Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2054490Z #16 478.6   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2056453Z #16 478.6
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2058823Z #16 478.6   × Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2061062Z #16 478.6   │ exit code: 1
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2066111Z #16 478.6   ╰─> [350 lines of output]
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2068068Z #16 478.6       running bdist_wheel
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2113917Z #16 478.6       running build
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2115833Z #16 478.6       running build_py
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2117549Z #16 478.6       creating build
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2119963Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2122533Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2125382Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent

2023-11-14T07:13:41.2488287Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue330.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2489292Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__api_timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2490590Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__ares_host_result.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2491832Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/_imports_imports_at_top_level.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2493013Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__destroy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2494377Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__subprocess_interrupted.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2495555Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_close.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2496705Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__hub.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2497823Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_stat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2498943Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue1864.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2500042Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue639.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2501366Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/_import_patch.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2502518Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_selectors.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2503704Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__import_blocking_in_greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2504870Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__backdoor.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2506040Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__core.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2507326Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__real_greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2508473Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test___config.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2509794Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test___monkey_patching.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2511000Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_ssl_warning.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2512153Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_watcher.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2513272Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_ex.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2514431Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__resolver_dnspython.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2515543Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__pool.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2516606Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__select.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2517859Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__subprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2519073Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__sleep0.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2520091Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_udp_server.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2521087Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/_import_wait.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2522055Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__hub_join.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2523058Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_callback.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2524059Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__environ.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2525078Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__hub_join_timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2526100Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__issues461_471.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2527168Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__threadpool_executor_patched.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2528211Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_ssl.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2529238Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_multiple_imports.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2530275Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__threading_no_monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2531277Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__iwait.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2532277Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_webproxy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2533508Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2534541Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libev/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2535671Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2536787Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libev/corecffi.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2537857Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libev/watcher.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2538862Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libuv
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2539898Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libuv/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libuv
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2541124Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libuv/loop.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libuv
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2542250Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libuv/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libuv
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2543379Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/libuv/watcher.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/libuv
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2544401Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2545450Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2546602Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/ares.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2547733Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/_addresses.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2548872Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2550118Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/_hostsfile.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2551245Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/blocking.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2552384Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/resolver/dnspython.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/resolver
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2553648Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2554851Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/**main**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2556086Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2557336Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue1526_no_monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2558649Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/threadpool_no_monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2559914Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/script.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2561202Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue1526_with_monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2562492Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue302monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2563799Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/threadpool_monkey_patches.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests/monkey_package
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2564963Z #16 478.6       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/testing/coveragesite
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2566176Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/testing/coveragesite/sitecustomize.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/testing/coveragesite
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2567422Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/badkey.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2568408Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/keycert.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2569598Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/2_7_keycert.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2570682Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/sha256.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2571790Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/nullcert.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2572991Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/badcert.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2574151Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/https_svn_python_org_root.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2575443Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/wrongcert.pem -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2576542Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/server.crt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2577617Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test_server.crt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2578713Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/hosts_file.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2579864Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_do_leakchecks.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2581071Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_monkeypatch.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2582256Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_use_resolver.txt -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2583615Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/test_server.key -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2584699Z #16 478.6       copying src/gevent/tests/server.key -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent/tests
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2585488Z #16 478.6       running build_ext
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2586520Z #16 478.6       generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38/gevent.libuv._corecffi.c'
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2587654Z #16 478.6       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-38
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2589023Z #16 478.6       Running '(cd  "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' in /tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2590191Z #16 478.6       ./configure: line 6350: cmp: command not found
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2590964Z #16 478.6       ./configure: line 6350: cmp: command not found
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2591750Z #16 478.6       ./configure: line 8279: diff: command not found
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2592810Z #16 478.6       config.status: error: in `/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/deps/libev': 2023-11-14T07:13:41.2593789Z #16 478.6       config.status: error: Something went wrong bootstrapping makefile fragments 2023-11-14T07:13:41.2594808Z #16 478.6           for automatic dependency tracking.  Try re-running configure with the 2023-11-14T07:13:41.2595838Z #16 478.6           '--disable-dependency-tracking' option to at least be able to build 2023-11-14T07:13:41.2596786Z #16 478.6           the package (albeit without support for automatic dependency tracking). 2023-11-14T07:13:41.2597647Z #16 478.6       See` config.log' for more details
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2598325Z #16 478.6       Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2599406Z #16 478.6         File "/opt/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2600251Z #16 478.6           main()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2601219Z #16 478.6         File "/opt/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2602211Z #16 478.6           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2603299Z #16 478.6         File "/opt/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2604283Z #16 478.6           return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2605418Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2606314Z #16 478.6           return self._build_with_temp_dir(
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2607425Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2608439Z #16 478.6           self.run_setup()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2609464Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2610333Z #16 478.6           exec(code, locals())
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2611062Z #16 478.6         File "", line 468, in 
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2611678Z #16 478.6         File "", line 337, in run_setup
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2612590Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 103, in setup
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2613500Z #16 478.6           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2614447Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2615213Z #16 478.6           return run_commands(dist)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2616447Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2617335Z #16 478.6           dist.run_commands()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2618359Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2619248Z #16 478.6           self.run_command(cmd)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2620213Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2621084Z #16 478.6           super().run_command(command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2622151Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2622996Z #16 478.6           cmd_obj.run()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2623985Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/normal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 369, in run
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2624831Z #16 478.6           self.run_command("build")
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2625868Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2626853Z #16 478.6           self.distribution.run_command(command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2627891Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2628735Z #16 478.6           super().run_command(command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2629765Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2630589Z #16 478.6           cmd_obj.run()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2631606Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2632511Z #16 478.6           self.run_command(cmd_name)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2633555Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2634462Z #16 478.6           self.distribution.run_command(command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2635505Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2636481Z #16 478.6           super().run_command(command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2637884Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2648640Z #16 478.6           cmd_obj.run()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2649631Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 141, in run
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2650684Z #16 478.6           ext.sources[0] = make_mod(self.build_temp, pre_run)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2651707Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4pjp05ms/overlay/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 126, in make_mod
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2652456Z #16 478.6           pre_run(ext, ffi)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2653761Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/_setuputils.py", line 393, in pre_run
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2654582Z #16 478.6           action()
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2655563Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/_setuplibev.py", line 55, in configure_libev
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2656435Z #16 478.6           system(libev_configure_command)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2657460Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/_setuputils.py", line 198, in system
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2658346Z #16 478.6           if _system(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs):
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2659534Z #16 478.6         File "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/*setuputils.py", line 194, in *system
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2660463Z #16 478.6           return check_call(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2661319Z #16 478.6         File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2662139Z #16 478.6           raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2663512Z #16 478.6       subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/tmp/pip-install-fm9qypdp/gevent_0b322961a213403e8ba354ff03b97ba0/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2664538Z #16 478.6       [end of output]
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2665110Z #16 478.6

2023-11-14T07:13:41.2665920Z #16 478.6   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2666895Z #16 478.6   ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
2023-11-14T07:13:41.2667639Z #16 478.6   Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): started
2023-11-14T07:14:31.6696623Z #16 529.2   Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2023-11-14T07:14:31.6700608Z #16 529.2   Created wheel for thrift: filename=thrift-0.16.0-cp38-cp38-linux_aarch64.whl size=400964 sha256=c7807d29cee3d9ed8ab4344897aa31f06b66233dbfba54fd98c761a003331d99
2023-11-14T07:14:31.6704777Z #16 529.2   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-sdao04r*/wheels/c1/03/53/7220f8aeecbf2c66ef655a9cff1929299e38119502a316ae30
2023-11-14T07:14:31.8204019Z #16 529.2 Successfully built validate_email uwsgi thrift
2023-11-14T07:14:31.8206185Z #16 529.2 Failed to build gevent
2023-11-14T07:14:31.8209365Z #16 529.2 ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1811989Z #16 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c microdnf -y install gcc-c++     && pip install wheel --no-cache-dir --no-binary=gevent --upgrade pip    && pip install --upgrade setuptools     && /tmp/pyinstall.sh $PYPI_USER $PYPI_PASSWORD /tmp/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1818233Z ------
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1826816Z  > [linux/arm64 compile-image 5/5] RUN microdnf -y install gcc-c++     && pip install wheel --no-cache-dir --no-binary=gevent --upgrade pip    && pip install --upgrade setuptools     && /tmp/pyinstall.sh *** *** /tmp/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir:
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1832613Z 478.6

2023-11-14T07:14:35.1837348Z 478.6   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1841089Z 478.6   ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1843416Z 478.6   Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): started
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1846176Z 529.2   Building wheel for thrift (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1850594Z 529.2   Created wheel for thrift: filename=thrift-0.16.0-cp38-cp38-linux_aarch64.whl size=400964 sha256=c7807d29cee3d9ed8ab4344897aa31f06b66233dbfba54fd98c761a003331d99
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1856303Z 529.2   Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-sdao04r*/wheels/c1/03/53/7220f8aeecbf2c66ef655a9cff1929299e38119502a316ae30
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1859601Z 529.2 Successfully built validate_email uwsgi thrift
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1861754Z 529.2 Failed to build gevent
2023-11-14T07:14:35.1864713Z 529.2 ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.